# Using SendMessage() Multi-threaded

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, message-queue

What happens if I use SendMessage() from different threads to one receiver? Imagine a situation, when receiver is still processing a message from Thread1 and Thread2 sends another message (with SendMessage()). What happens in the receiver end? Does it stop execution of Message1, process Message2 and after finishing with Message2 returns to Message1 back? Or does Message2 waits for end of Message1?

Comment: Message1 _could_ get preempted during that processing if the code enters an alterable wait state, which would allow Message2 to get processed.  So the order and atomicity of message handling is not guaranteed.

Comment: The second message is dispatched when the thread calls a message-processing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic rule is: The only time a thread dispatches cross-thread sent messages is, when calling a message-retrieval function ([GetMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx), [PeekMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx), etc.) on that thread. The message-retrieval functions first check for any cross-thread sent messages, dispatch them one after another, and then move on to retrieve a message from the thread's message queue.

This has 2 consequences:

- Cross-thread sent messages are dispatched, when the receiving thread is not handling<sup>1)</sup> any queued messages.
- Cross-thread sent messages are dispatched, when the receiving thread is not handling<sup>1)</sup> any other cross-thread sent message.

In your particular example, the receiver will continue to handle Message1 until finished, and move on to dispatch Message2 the next time it calls a message-retrieval function.

There is one notable exception to this rule: A thread that is waiting for [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) to return can dispatch inbound cross-thread sent messages<sup>2)</sup>. This means that there is a potential for re-entrancy. Taking your example again, suppose that the message handler for Message1 at some point calls `SendMessage`, it could well be, that Message2 is dispatched before handling of Message1 continues.

To sum it up:

- Cross-thread sent messages are dispatched serially on the receiving thread.
- There are several, well-defined times, when a thread dispatches cross-thread sent messages.
- While cross-thread sent messages are never handled concurrently, there are no atomicity rules; be prepared for re-entrancy.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Assuming that calling a message-retrieval function is not part of normal message handling.
<sup>2)</sup> See [When can a thread receive window messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040608-00/?p=38983) for details on why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the question is about messages being sent to a particular window i.e. a HWND other than NULL or HWND_BROADCAST, and that the window is owned by a thread belonging to the same process .

In this case, the thread that created the target window will receive the message next time GetMessage is called with a filter that includes the given window. The sending thread will be  blocked until the receiving thread actually completes processing of the message.

If, while processing the message from Thread1, the receiving thread calls GetMessage/DispatchMessage again, then any pending message (including messages possibly sent by Thread2) will be processed at that point, then control will return to processing of the message from Thread1.

From the docs for the [SendMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx):

> If the specified window was created by the calling thread, the window procedure is called immediately as a subroutine. If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code. The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message.

Comment: I've always found this 'switches to that thread' statement controversial. The fact is that it doesn't: it engages in hat is described next,  which isn't a thread switch in any sense but a block and a post of some kind.

Comment: @EJP Right, that's a bit misleading as phrased, and the net effect is what you describe. FWIW the quote comes straight from the official MSDN docs, and (on a quick check) it hasn't changed since at least 2001.